# Algorithm for trying to sort people into 4 different groups based on different attributes

Tags: statistics, algorithms

I have objects with the following data structure:

```
{
id: 1,
values: 
    { 
    "lime": 48, 
    "fuchsia": 29, 
    "silver": 27, 
     "turq": 74 
     }
}
```

I need to **sort these elements into $4$ different groups**. The rules:

- The groups need to be the same size-ish (elements.length + elements mod length, for example with $75$ elements,  the groups would be $18$ people and the remaining $3$ people would be divided into their corresponding locations).
- The group they're sorted into is ideally their highest score of the four, but if the group is full, they need to go somewhere else.

**What I'm looking for is an idea of how to approach this**, not programming help - which is why I'm writing here and not StackOverflow. My previous solution was very crude: I loop through, add each element to an array of their highest color, and then try to fix it by checking if there's any arrays that are bigger than elements.length + modulo, and move those to their second highest value. It doesn't work, I've been getting very erratic results.

Now I've updated the solution to first check if there is room, then add the element to its color array; if no room, add it to next highest, etc. The code example is linked below.

Additional information:

- This is for an art project - an interactive theatre piece. The elements are people, who will be divided into groups and physically different parts of the theatre space corresponding to a colour group.
- Because the amount of elements is a maximum of $100$ (the space doesn't fit more), complexity or algorithm speed is not really important. The calculation takes place during monologues - being lightning-fast is not a priority.
- All the fields always have a value. "turq" stands for turquoise, lol.
- I'm programming this in JavaScript/TypeScript, if anyone wants to know.

EDIT:
Here's a larger dataset. I added the result of my current algorithm to the JSON -> https://ctxt.io/2/AAAQT7ogFQ

This is an example result I got:

```
lime (12): 5, 38, 150, 79, 65, 43, 99, 23, 24, 6, 2, 7,
fuchsia (13): 8, 17, 18, 96, 666, 15, 34, 69, 21, 18, 27, 3, 91,
silver (13): 2, 47, 0, 39, 67, 26, 11512, 123, 74, 28, 26, 22, 19,
turq (11): 45, 57, 89, 136, 8, 10, 30, 29, 12, 82, 83,
```

Here's the current algorithm that output this result: https://ctxt.io/2/AACQ4Et0Ew

The issue that I have is the following: even though all the stuff is equally sorted and MOST is OK, there are a few that didn't fit at the correct time, and for example with this dataset, the "fuchsia" result array contains an element like this:
[example of element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rU66.png)

A good result would not let that big of a difference happen - so if the difference is that large, they should definitely be put into their first choice. But how do I determine this?

Appreciate the help.

Comment: This is (potentially) an interesting problem. We need more information. If you [edit] the question to show us a small example where your algorithm fails (explain why) and what you would consider better we might be able to help. Maybe see https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/81698/algorithm-for-sorting-people-into-groups-by-preference-and-score

Comment: @EthanBolker I updated the post with a lot of extra data. The last progress was that I got them to be the same size.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible way to avoid what happened to #91 in your example.

1. Start by normalizing everyone's preferences so that they are percentages - scale them to sum to 100.
2. Sort the people using the largest preference. Then use your algorithm assigning people to groups starting with the ones who have the highest top preference.
3. If the preferred group is full, you could give that person their second choice

This will favor the people with the strongest feeling about what they most want.

An alternative to step 2 is to put someone aside if their first choice group is full. When you've processed everyone,  sort the unassigned people by their second choices and run the loop again. I think this will be more complicated. It might be somewhat fairer most of the time but runs the risk of giving a few people their last choice. You might want to experiment.